# How to convert Decimal number to Date and Time in Java?

Tags: java, android, date, time, decimal

Hi I am working on Flash air wifi sdcard application.And this application I want latest modified files. I have the decimal Date and decimal Time values.

See this :

`/DCIM,0126_1.jpg,70408,32,17642,28040` and See this formate `<directory>, <filename>, <size>, <attribute>, <date>, <time>`

Here `17071` is `<date>` and `28040` is `<time>`.

see full document [here](https://www.flashair-developers.com/en/documents/api/commandcgi/#100)

For converting `17642` decimal value into Date I tried this code :

Case 1 :

```
 String datastring="1.76.42";
 SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss");
 Date converttoData = sf.parse(datastring);

 outPut : Thu Jan 01 02:16:42 GMT+05:30 1970
```

and

Case 2 :

```
  Date date = new Date(17642);
  outPut : Thu Jan 01 05:30:17 GMT+05:30 1970
```

In case one I am getting `02:16:42` and case I am getting different time `05:30:17` remaining same.

But,I created that file in `Thu July 10 2014` at `19:08:20`.

So, How I can convert this decimal number into exact Date and Time.

Comment: According to the document you linked, you will need to do [bit manipulation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) to get the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String dateStr = "17642";
String timeStr = "28040";

int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(dateStr);
int timeInt = Integer.parseInt(timeStr);

GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(1980 + ((dateInt >> 9) & 0x1FF),
        ((dateInt >> 5) & 0xF) - 1,
        dateInt & 0x1F,
        ((timeInt >> 11) & 0x1F),
        ((timeInt >> 5) & 0x3F),
        (timeInt & 0x1F) / 2);

System.out.println("Message: " + gc.getTime());
```

result:

> Message: Thu Jul 10 13:44:04 CEST 2014

The date is as you say. The time isn't, but I'm quite sure it's correct because:

```
28040 -> 0110110110001000 ->
  hr:    01101 == 13
  min:   101100 == 44
  sec/2: 01000 == 8

=> time 13:44:4.5
```

Comment: Another ref https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/external/fat32lib/+/8053088ccd55a94d6643a12660e967a5e8dfd5de/src/main/java/de/waldheinz/fs/fat/DosUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google gave the following solution for converting the date format to YYYYMMDD, which you can then parse. Using this and the specs you should be able to work out the time function as well.

```
public String getDate(Integer date, String sep) {
    return String.format("%04d", ((date >> 9) & 0x1FF)+1980)+sep+
        String.format("%02d", (date >> 5) & 0xF)+sep+
        String.format("%02d", date & 0x1F);
}
```